# check, disable and set a radio input when another one is checked React

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm trying to check, disable and set the radio input called "Histogramme" to "Non" when my radio input called "1 - Aucun agrégat" is checked to get something like this :

[image]

---

Source Code

```js
interface IConfig {
    aggregationEnabled: number[],
    formatEnabled: number[]
    cartographieEnabled: number[]
    histogrammeEnabled: number[]
}

const ReportLayoutSetter = (props: {
    reportConfig: ReportConfiguration,
    update: (title: string, comment: string, aggregation: number, sharing: number, format: number, mapping: string, histograms: string) => void
}) => {

const [config, setConfig] = useState<IConfig>()
const [aggregationDomain, setAggregationDomain] = useState<{name: string, code: number}[]>([])
const [histogrammeDomain, setHistogrammeDomain] = useState<{name: string, code: number}[]>([])

const updateHistogramme = (event: any) => {
        const newHistogramme = event.target.value
        props.update(props.reportConfig.title, props.reportConfig.comment, props.reportConfig.aggregation, props.reportConfig.sharing, props.reportConfig.format, props.reportConfig.mapping, newHistogramme)
    }

return (
<tr>
  <td className="name"> Histogramme </td>
  <td className="value column-3">
    {histogrammeDomain.map((codedValue) => (
      <label
        className={
          !config?.histogrammeEnabled.includes(codedValue.code)
            ? "text-gray"
            : ""
        }
      >
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="histogrammeSelection"
          value={codedValue.code}
          checked={props.reportConfig.histograms === String(codedValue.code)}
          onChange={updateHistogramme}
          disabled={props.reportConfig.aggregation == 1 ? true : false}
        />
        {codedValue.name}
      </label>
    ))}
  </td>
</tr>
)

}
```

```
interface ReportConfiguration {
    objectid: number|undefined,
    title: string,
    comment: string,
    aggregation: number,
    sharing: number,
    format: number,
    mapping: string,
    histograms: string,
    folder_list: FolderListConfiguration|undefined,
    author: string
}
```

My code above allows me only to disable the option "Histogramme" but it does not set the radio input automatically to "Non" when I check "1- aucune agrégat". Does anyone have an idea how to do that in React?

check set and disable a radio input when another one is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, I had to change the checked property as :

```
<tr>
 <td className="name"> Histogramme </td>
 <td className="value column-3">
       {histogrammeDomain.map(codedValue =>
         <label className = {!config?.histogrammeEnabled.includes(codedValue.code) ? 'text-gray' : ''}
           >
           <input type="radio"
             name="histogrammeSelection"
             value={codedValue.code}
             checked={props.reportConfig.aggregation == 1 || props.reportConfig.histograms === String(codedValue.code)}
             onChange={updateHistogramme}
             disabled={props.reportConfig.aggregation == 1 ? true : false || !config?.histogrammeEnabled.includes(codedValue.code)}
             />
             {codedValue.name}
             </label>
          )}
  </td>
</tr>
```